# Is it possible to use mysql group_concat over two cols to get results in one col?

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT a.sec_id as sid, r.rank
FROM `0_area` AS a
LEFT JOIN `0_rank` AS r ON a.rank_id = r.id
WHERE a.user_id = $id
GROUP BY a.sec_id
```

which returns me rows with two columns. As:

```
sid | rank
2   | user
3   | mod
4   | admin
```

I want to use it in another query, while putting the two returned rows in one column, possibly using a group_concat as in this example. The example below is not working at this moment

```
SELECT m.id, m.nom, a.sec_id, a.rank, GROUP_CONCAT( cast( DISTINCT a.sec_id # r.rank 
ORDER BY a.sec_id ASC
SEPARATOR ',' ) AS char ) AS levels
FROM `0_member` AS m
LEFT JOIN `0_area` AS a ON m.id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN `0_rank` AS r ON r.id = a.rank_id
WHERE a.sec_id =2
ORDER BY m.nom ASC
```

Thanks.

PS. Error that I'm getting is: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT a.sec_id # r.rank ORDER BY a.sec_id ASC SEPARATOR ',') as char ) as lev' at line 1

Comment: First: your first query does not make sense, and is not valid SQL (though valid MySql) since r.rank is not well defined. Secondly: no you can't (as far as I know). Thirdly: Could you explain what you really want - there is likely a good solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This solved it.

```
GROUP_CONCAT( cast( concat( a.sec_id, \': \', a.rank ) AS char ) SEPARATOR \', \') AS ranks
```